# Is Ring\Ideal equal to Ring-Ideal as sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal.

Is $R \setminus I = \{r \in R : r \notin I\}$ equal to the set $R - I =\{r- i : r \in R, i\in I\}$?

I think that they are the same but could not show whether it is true or false.

Comment: Hint: Try with the $0$-ideal.

Comment: But in set theory, $A\setminus B$ and $A-B$ are both notations used by authors to refer to set difference $\{x\in A\mid x\notin B\}$. I have never seen anyone ever use the set $\{x-y\mid x\in A,y\in B\}$ under any circumstance. Is that the confusion?

Comment: Notice that, due to the definition of ideal, $R-I=R+I$. Since the RHS is the usual sum of ideals, $R+I=R$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is false. $R\setminus I\subset R$ contains no elements of $I$, but as $0\in R\cap I$, clearly $0\in R-I$ since $0-0=0$. So the two are never equal as sets.

Comment: +1. This is why you should always try at least one example before conjecturing something . . .